# Add jackson scala dependency to Datastax spark intergration

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly how to add `jackson-module-scala` to my datastax spark integration.

I am using **Datastax Enterprise 4.5**, planning to upgrade soon to 4.6.1 soon.

I am still new to scala, though I have some experience with maven. I understand that `dse` uses the spark-cassandra-connector under the hood, but I can't find where the connector code resides on a specific cassandra node, specifically the `build.sbt` file.

Would I even add the `jackson-module-scala` dependency to the connector `build.sbt` file? I grepped for an `.sbt` file but could not find one.

Any help here much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sbt is the scala build tool.

You should have a scala project where you use spark.

this project should have a `build.sbt` file that lists dependencies and a lot more.

you should add the jackson dependency to that file